# Simple Bootstrap xs break-point layout looks very different on mobile and PC (HELP)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive

I will go ahead and apologize if this subject has already been covered (although I have, as yet, not been able to find it on Stack Exchange). I'm trying to learn the grid system and have listened to a number of lectures. For practice, I'm trying to display three images in the container-row-col structure. The problem is that my simple bootstrap grid set-up is displaying properly on my computer at what I think is the xs break point but not on mobile. The padding on the latter seems to be both excessive (gutter is almost as large as one of the images) and asymmetric on the sides. I have included screen shots of both below.

I have tried commenting out the css file (which I just use to add padding to the tops and bottoms of the col) just in case that somehow was interfering with bootstraps natural styling. That did nothing. Any help on making the PC view and mobile sites look less incongruous would be much appreciated! (code below images)

PC view of xs break-point:
[image: PC view of xs break-point]

Mobile view of xs-breakpoint:
[image: Mobile view of xs-breakpoint]

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 top-buffer">
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/spartacus/images/5/55/Juliuscaesar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130606052819" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
             </div>      
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 top-buffer">
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/spartacus/images/5/55/Juliuscaesar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130606052819" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
             </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 top-buffer">
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/spartacus/images/5/55/Juliuscaesar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130606052819" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
             </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

(below is the main.css file)

```
   .top-buffer {
margin-top: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is perplexed by this, I will say that the solution is to include the following tag in your html head: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

Use 'sm' for mobile. 'xs' might not be getting rendered because the screen size is larger than the parameters for `xs`. See if using 'sm' for mobile screen works or not!

Edit 1: Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 top-buffer">
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/spartacus/images/5/55/Juliuscaesar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130606052819" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
             </div>      
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 top-buffer">
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/spartacus/images/5/55/Juliuscaesar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130606052819" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
             </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 top-buffer">
                <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/spartacus/images/5/55/Juliuscaesar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130606052819" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
             </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

I think you are specifying a row, and then in `xs`, using 18 columns in total, which while trying to fit themselves, mess up the padding. In above code, i have removed `row` and added `sm`.

Comment: I would not think that replacing 'xs' with 'sm' would make a difference since, by default, bootstrap will assume that the column value is the same as the xs for every other cut off unless told otherwise. So, for this case, by setting xs to 6 we also set sm to 6. However, out of an abundance of caution, I have tried implementing your solution (as best I understand). Unfortunately, I still get the same result...  Any other thoughts? I must be making a really obvious mistake....

Comment: Remember, there are 12 columns in one row, and if you want three images, then use 4 col for each image. In `xs` you have used 6 col. If you want three images, replace 6 by 4.

Comment: Right. So for the xs view, I *would* like to have two images per row. That's fine. But I want the padding to be the same on mobile as it is on PC. I'm just racking my brain over here as to why my phone's display would 1) increase the size of the padding and 2) give more padding to the right of the images than to the left. The larger display gives the expected results for all breakpoints which is the really confusing thing....

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either on mobile (but still works fine on all sizes on PC...) Also, while I am too inexperienced to rule out the possibility that the problem could be using greater-than-12 column sums, I am not convinced. My understanding is that best practice dictates that columns should always be included in rows and that exceeding 12 is ok *if* done in the context of creating a wrapping effect for responsive design. Here is a link to an article I just read while researching this: http://blog.codeply.com/2015/06/24/when-to-use-bootstraps-row-class/